# List state on jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to implement a state that can change when a fetch an API, but I could not implemented yet. This is my code:

```
var individualChats by remember {
    mutableStateOf(listOf<ChatData>())
}
```

This is my data class:

```
data class ChatData(val name: String, val image: String)
```

When I use simple list without remember and mutableStateOf it's take but not render I must to force it, but with state not render.
And this is that I want to do:

```
LaunchedEffect(SharedApp.sharedIndividualChats) {
    individualChats = SharedApp.sharedIndividualChats
}
```

and this is the function that I want to render:

```
@Composable
fun chatList(chats: List<ChatData>) {
    if (chats.isEmpty()) {
        Text(text = "You not have chats")
    }else {
        LazyColumn() {
            items(chats) { chat -> itemListIndividual(name = chat.name, image = chat.image)}
        }
    }
}
```

I try the mutableStateListOf, but I get an error.

Comment: My guess is that you're expecting your view to update when `SharedApp.sharedIndividualChats` updates, but it should be `mutableStateOf`/`mutableStateListOf` to do so. If that's not the case, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for answer but my main problem is how to create a list state in compose, for fetching data from API, because mutableStateOf and mutableStateListOf do not work for me. But I can try something. Thanks!

Comment: There is almost no case where a singleton global synchronously accessable list is correct, so you might want to encapsulate that list as LiveData/MutableStateFlow/BehaviorRelay and use observeAsState/collectAsState/subscribeAsState respectively

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing something similar and declaring it this way worked:

```
var individualChats: List<ChatData> by remember {
    mutableStateOf(listOf())
}
```